# meteor / minimongo working with nested data objects

Tags: meteor

I am trying to find the best way to do CRUD operations on a document that has a embedded document. [1 Business --> Many Services]

I have an business object that looks like this:

```
{
        _id: "ZChonAoaksZ7kCvca",
        name: "ABC",
        description: "random description",
        services: [
            { _id: "ZChonAoaksZ7kCvcf", service:"123", bufferEnd: 5 },
            { _id: "ZChonAoaksZ7kCvcg", service: "345", bufferEnd: 5 },
            { _id: "ZChonAoaksZ7kCvch", service: "567", bufferEnd: 5 },
        ]
}
```

Selections: i query my collection using:

```
collectionname.find({'services._id': 'ZChonAoaksZ7kCvcf'}).fetch()
```

as expected it simply returns the entire document. How can i return only the single sub document not the business object or an entire array? Is there a way just to get one item from the parent document such as:

```
{ _id: "ZChonAoaksZ7kCvcf", service:"123", bufferEnd: 5 }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 3 CRUD operations to edit Arrays within a MongoDB object from Meteor (care Update is the tricky one) are as follows:

**Add a new item to document array:**

```
Business.update({ _id: Business.findOne()._id }, {
    $addToSet: {
        services: {
            _id: Random.id(),
            service: $('#new_service_name').val(),
            bufferEnd: $('#new_service_description').val(),
        }
    }
);
```

**Edit an existing item in document array**

```
var bus = Business.findOne().services;
var indexToUpdate = _.indexOf(_.pluck(bus, '_id'), Session.get('Service_selectedId'));

var modifier = { $set: {} };
modifier.$set["services." + indexToUpdate + ".service"] = $('#service_name').val();
modifier.$set["services." + indexToUpdate + ".description"] = $('#service_description').val();

Business.update(Business.findOne()._id, modifier);
```

**Delete Operation**

```
Business.update({ _id: Business.findOne()._id }, {
    $pull: { services: { _id: Session.get('Service_selectedId') } }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the result after it's fetched:

```
var wholeDoc = Documents.findOne({'services._id': 'ZChonAoaksZ7kCvcf'});

var service = _.find(wholeDoc.services, function(service) {
  return service._id === 'ZChonAoaksZ7kCvcf',
});
```